Find fundamental period of $\sin(5π× g(3x))$ and $\sin^2(5π × g(3x))$. $g(x)$ denotes fractional part of $x$. (Verifying my method)
The question- Find fundamental period of $\sin(5π× g(3x))$ and $\sin^2(5π × g(3x))$.
$g(x)$ denotes fractional part of $x$
Note- (fractional part of x = $x-[x]$), $[x]$ is greatest integer function)
My attempt- (I have not written sin again and again as it would be messy)
by simplifying I get ,
$f(x)= 15πx-5π[x]$
and $f(x+t)= 15πx+15πt-5π[3x+3t]$
We already know $1/3$ is a period so I assume $t<(1/3)$
So $[3x+3t]$ will be either 0 or 1 when $[3x]$=0
So $f(x)=15πx$ and $f(x+t)=15πx+15πt$ or
$f(x+t)=15πx+15πt-5π$
Now, if I take only $\sin$ as outer, I see that no t satisfies such that$f(x)=f(x+t)$, so fundamental period$=(1/3)$
If I take $\sin^2$, I see $t=(1/15)$ satisfies, so fundamental period $=(1/15)$
Am I right to conclude what is I said in the last step?

Quick tip: when typing trig functions use \sin to make it render as $\sin$ instead of $sin$

For verification questions (I added the tag), you have to "identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so".
